# How to write content into pdf? Google Cloud Storage Service

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pdf, google-cloud-storage

How can i create a pdf into gcs, and also insert some data?

This is my code:

> ```
> GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(new RetryParams.Builder()
>             .initialRetryDelayMillis(10)
>             .retryMaxAttempts(10)
>             .totalRetryPeriodMillis(15000)
>             .build());
>
>           GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename("areteaics", "test.pdf");
>           GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("application/pdf").build();
>           GcsOutputChannel writeChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(filename,options);           
>           PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(Channels.newWriter(writeChannel, "UTF8"));
>           //out.println("The woods are lovely dark and deep.");
>           //out.println("But I have promises to keep.");
>           //out.flush();
>           writeChannel.waitForOutstandingWrites();
>           //writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("And miles to go before I sleep.".getBytes()));
>           writeChannel.close();
> ```

Comment: The problem its that when i try to open the pdf file - in the console of the cloud storage - , said that the file its corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are creating a pdf formatted file (you're just making a file with the extension pdf). You need to use a library like [itext](http://itextpdf.com/) to create the pdf file and then write it to cloudstorage.

e.g using itext to write to outputstream [src](http://floonit.blogspot.de/2012/07/generate-pdf-using-google-app-engine.html):

```
   Document document = new Document();
   PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
   document.open();
   document.add(new Paragraph("This is a paragraph"));
   document.close();
```

You'd need to modify the above code to write to gcs (instead of response outputstream).